# Is it possible to use the 'Split' tool in Python?

Tags: python, scripting, mesh

I was wondering if it is possible to activate the 'Split' tool in python. I'd like to make a script that loops through the selected objects polygons and splits them, creating an object with all its faces separated from each other. Is this possible? If not, is there a work-around? If none of this is possible, then could one make a script where it selects a face of an object, and selects the next face when the user presses the <kbd>Y</kbd> key (the hotkey for 'Split')? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the [bmesh api](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bmesh.html?highlight=bmesh#bmesh).
The operator you are looking for is [`bmesh.ops.split`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=split#bmesh.ops.split).

However, the functionality you want to create is already in blender, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>*> Edge split*, or [`bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=edge_split#bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split)

Note that you could also create and apply an *Edge split* modifier, however it's probably easier to use the `edge_split` operator.

---

As for selecting the "next face", you can select a face by setting its [`select`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.select) value to `True`:

[`bpy.context.object`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.context.html?highlight=bpy.context.object#bpy.context.object) > [`data`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Object.html?#bpy.types.Object.data) > [`polygons`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.polygons) > [`select`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.select)

E.g. `bpy.context.object.data.polygons[0].select = True` will select the face with an index of `0` in the active object.

Note that you [have to be in object mode for this to work](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Mesh.html#mesh-data):

> The mesh data is accessed in object mode and intended for compact storage, for more flexible mesh editing from python see [`bmesh`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bmesh.html#module-bmesh).

You can set the mode with the [`mode_set`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=mode#bpy.ops.object.mode_set) operator, e.g. `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')`

How you define the "next face" is up to you, as AFAIK there is no absolute definition of which face should be the "next" one.